# how to boot sabrelite linux image on qemu

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux, qemu, imx6

What is the right command to boot sabrelite linux kernel on qemu.
I've linux kernel **zImage** and rootfs of type **ext3**

I'm trying to boot kernel with following command line but there is **no any console output.**

```
./qemu-system-arm -M sabrelite -m 1G -kernel zImage -smp 4 -drive file=console-image-mx6q-rootfs.ext3,format=raw,id=mycard -device sd-card,drive=mycard -append "console=ttymxc1,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p0 rootfstype=ext3 rw" -dtb zImage-imx6q-sabresd.dtb
```

QEMU : 3.0.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues getting the rootfs to mount correctly on IMX6 emulated with Qemu; this Q&A on SO solved the issue:
[Qemu Freescale i.MX6 DualLite SABRE : root filesystem does not mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47538951/qemu-freescale-i-mx6-duallite-sabre-root-filesystem-does-not-mount)

It did involve patching the Qemu codebase, but that was a year back; so now, using the latest ver, hopefully it works..

FYI, this is the command I used to launch it:

```
qemu-system-arm -m 2048 -M sabrelite -kernel <path-to-zImage> -drive  file=<path-to-my-rfs.img>,format=raw,id=mysdcard -device sd-card,drive=mysdcard -append "console=ttymxc0 rootfstype=ext4 root=/dev/mmcblk0 rw rootwait init=/sbin/init" -no-reboot -nographic -dtb <path-to>/imx6dl-sabresd.dtb
```

HTH..